# Filtering ON sub query only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns four columns and i want to apply a date range/filter to the two of the columns only , Previously i wrote My query as below.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Collector.name, 
       dbo.Debtor.batchno AS batchno, 
       COUNT(dbo.Debtor.id) AS cases, 
       SUM(dbo.Debtor.totalDebt) AS amount, 
       SUM(dbo.Payment.payment) AS collection,
       SUM(dbo.Debtor.balance) AS OSBalance, 
       dbo.debtor.receivedDate    
  FROM dbo.Payment WITH (NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Collector WITH (NOLOCK) 
             ON dbo.Payment.collectorid = dbo.Collector.id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Debtor WITH (NOLOCK) 
             ON dbo.Payment.debtorid = dbo.Debtor.id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Client WITH (NOLOCK) 
             ON dbo.debtor.clientid = dbo.Client.id   
 WHERE dbo.Payment.paymentdate BETWEEN ' 2011-02-27 00:00:00.000 ' 
                                   AND  '2014-02-27 23:59:59.000'     
       AND dbo.Payment.confirmed='Y' 
GROUP BY  
       dbo.Collector.name, 
       dbo.Debtor.batchno,
       dbo.debtor.receivedDate 
ORDER BY 
       dbo.debtor.receivedDate DESC
```

The above filter all the columns by the paymentdate. However i want the filter by payment date to apply to only two columns namely cases and collecton like below.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Collector.name, 
       dbo.Debtor.batchno AS batchno,
       (
   SELECT COUNT(dbo.Debtor.id) 
   FROM dbo.Debtor d INNER JOIN dbo.Payment p ON d.id = p.debtorid
   WHERE paymentdate BETWEEN ' 2011-02-27 00:00:00.000 ' 
                          AND  '2014-02-27 23:59:59.000' 
          AND batchno=dbo.Debtor.batchno 
           AND dbo.collector.name= dbo.collector.name
   ) AS cases, 
       SUM(dbo.Debtor.totalDebt) AS amount, 
       (
        SELECT SUM(dbo.Payment.payment) 
         FROM dbo.Payment 
        WHERE paymentdate BETWEEN ' 2011-02-27 00:00:00.000 ' 
                              AND  '2014-02-27 23:59:59.000' 
              AND batchno= dbo.Debtor.batchno 
              AND name= dbo.collector.name
         ) AS collection,
       SUM(dbo.Debtor.balance) AS OSBalance, 
       dbo.debtor.receivedDate    
  FROM dbo.Payment WITH (NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Collector WITH (NOLOCK) 
             ON dbo.Payment.collectorid = dbo.Collector.id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Debtor WITH (NOLOCK) 
             ON dbo.Payment.debtorid = dbo.Debtor.id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Client WITH (NOLOCK) 
             ON dbo.debtor.clientid = dbo.Client.id   
 WHERE dbo.Payment.confirmed='Y' 
GROUP BY 
       dbo.Collector.name, 
       dbo.Debtor.batchno,
       dbo.debtor.receivedDate 
ORDER BY 
       dbo.debtor.receivedDate DESC
```

The above doesnt work for me. Also i want to group by only batchno and name. Plus the collection and cases columns must filter by payment date . Pls how do i achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated. warmest regard

Comment: Thank you sirs for the correction. It isnt mysql but rather MSSQL 2008. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't work for you how? Where is your table structure?

Comment: SOorry guys. It works now. Previously was repeating the same value. Will update my query now.